# Dsolve svars error: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables

Tags: differential-equations

New to Mathematica, trying to solve a set of coupled differential equations related to a geodesics/Calculus of Variations problem. More specifically, I am trying to solve the two Euler-Lagrange equations minimizing the arc length of a curve along the unit sphere.

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial u} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{u}} = 0 \\[10pt]
\frac{\partial L}{\partial v} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{v}} = 0
\end{align}

where L is the Lagrangian of the arc-length functional for a curve along a sphere parameterized by $(u,v)$:

\begin{align}
L(\xi,\dot{\xi}) = \sqrt{\cos^2(v)\dot{u}^2 + 1}
\end{align}

The resulting differential equation is:

```
{(2 Cos[v[t]] Sin[v[t]] Derivative[1][u][t] Derivative[1][v][t])/Sqrt[
   1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t]^2] - (
   Cos[v[t]]^2 (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t])/Sqrt[
   1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][
      t]^2] + (Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][
       t] (-2 Cos[v[t]] Sin[v[t]] Derivative[1][u][t]^2 Derivative[1][
          v][t] + 2 Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t] (
          u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]))/(2 (1 + 
        Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t]^2)^(3/2)) == 
  0, -((Cos[v[t]] Sin[v[t]] Derivative[1][u][t]^2)/Sqrt[
   1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t]^2]) == 0}
```

And the DSolve expression is:

```
DSolve[{(2 Cos[v[t]] Sin[v[t]] Derivative[1][u][t] Derivative[1][v][
      t])/Sqrt[1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t]^2] - (
    Cos[v[t]]^2 (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t])/Sqrt[
    1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][
       t]^2] + (Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][
        t] (-2 Cos[v[t]] Sin[v[t]] Derivative[1][u][t]^2 Derivative[
           1][v][t] + 
         2 Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t] (u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
           t]))/(2 (1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t]^2)^(3/2)) == 
   0, -((Cos[v[t]] Sin[v[t]] Derivative[1][u][t]^2)/Sqrt[
    1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t]^2]) == 0}, {v[t], u[t]}, t]
```

I seem to have two (possibly unsolvable) equations with two variables each defined by the parameter t. And yet Mathematica returns a *"Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables"* error. The equation doesn't seem underspecified, and I'd expect an "equation cannot be solved with methods available to DSolve" error if it were simply unsolvable. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The problem seems to be the last equation, which generically implies `u'[t] == 0`; which in turn implies `u''[t] = 0` and the system is satisfied by any `v[t]` as long as `u[t]` is constant.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. That really should have been obvious to me, in part because it's the answer I was expecting. This is the geodesic minimization problem on a sphere, and the solution curve should be one of the so-called great circles of the sphere, characterized by a constant polar angle. 

Wikipedia literally says: "Since the starting point and ending point are fixed, S is minimized if and only if φ' = 0, so the curve must lie on a meridian of the sphere φ = φ0 = constant."

So it all makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DSolve` rewrites the system as a system of first order equations and then tries to `Solve` for the derivatives.

One can see the `Solve` command `DSolve` calls by using `Trace` as follows:

```
Trace[
 DSolve[{(2 Cos[v[t]] Sin[v[t]] Derivative[1][u][t] Derivative[1][v][
         t])/Sqrt[
       1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t]^2] - (Cos[v[t]]^2 u''[t])/
      Sqrt[1 + 
        Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t]^2] + (Cos[
          v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][
         t] (-2 Cos[v[t]] Sin[
            v[t]] Derivative[1][u][t]^2 Derivative[1][v][t] + 
          2 Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t] u''[t]))/(2 (1 + 
           Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t]^2)^(3/2)) == 
    0, -((Cos[v[t]] Sin[v[t]] Derivative[1][u][t]^2)/
       Sqrt[1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][u][t]^2]) == 0}, {v[t], 
   u[t]}, t],
 _Solve,
 TraceInternal -> True]
```

The `Solve` command is as follows (possibly with different local variables):

```
Solve[{-((Cos[v[t]]^2 Derivative[1][NDSolve`u$1][t])/Sqrt[
         1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 NDSolve`u$1[t]^2]) + (
    2 Cos[v[t]] Sin[v[t]] NDSolve`u$1[t] Derivative[1][v][t])/Sqrt[
        1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 NDSolve`u$1[
       t]^2] + (Cos[v[t]]^2 NDSolve`u$1[
            t] (2 Cos[v[t]]^2 NDSolve`u$1[t] Derivative[1][NDSolve`u$1][
           t] - 2 Cos[v[t]] Sin[v[t]] NDSolve`u$1[t]^2 Derivative[1][
               v][t]))/(2 (1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 NDSolve`u$1[t]^2)^(3/2)) == 
   0, -((Cos[v[t]] Sin[v[t]] NDSolve`u$1[t]^2)/Sqrt[
        1 + Cos[v[t]]^2 NDSolve`u$1[t]^2]) == 0, 
  Derivative[1][u][t] == NDSolve`u$1[t]}, {Derivative[1][u][t], 
      Derivative[1][NDSolve`u$1][t], Derivative[1][v][t]}]
```

> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>

```
(*
  {{Derivative[1][u][t] -> NDSolve`u$1[t], 
        Derivative[1][NDSolve`u$1][t] -> 0}}
*)
```

The solution returned is incomplete and unusable by `DSolve`, so `DSolve` quits.  I suppose it would be nicer if it caught the error message and reissued a message more easily understood by the user.

(The source of the problem seems to be the last equation in the OP's system, which generically implies `u'[t] == 0`.  This in turn implies `u''[t] = 0`.  By plugging these values into the system, one can see that `v[t]` can be any function as long as `u[t]` is constant.)